# Remove and return xml blocks from same LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Name>Let Us C</Name>
        <Price>250</Price>
        <ID>234</ID>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>Da Vinci Code</Name>
        <Price>500</Price>
        <ID>38</ID>
    </Book>

    <Book>
        <Name>Data Structures through C++</Name>
        <Price>250</Price>
        <ID>234</ID>
    </Book>


</Books>
```

I need to remove all the Books with the given ID(say 234) and also the LINQ query should return me the ID and name of the removed books as a keyValue pair. Is it possible to be done using the same LINQ query?

I wrote the following to remove the book with ID 38. But I am not able to get the ID and name without having to iterate it again.

```
var idsToRemove  = new List<int>{{38}};
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("sample.xml");

xmlDoc.Descendants("Book")
                .Where(
                    Book =>
                    (Book.Element("ID") != null
                    && idsToRemove.Contains(Convert.ToInt32((string) Book.Element("ID").Value)))).Select(Book => Book).Remove();
```

**EDIT 1:**

Code to select the key value pairs for the given book Id.

```
var result = xmlDoc.Descendants("Book")
                .Where(
                    Book =>
                    (Book.Element("ID") != null
                    && idsToRemove.Contains(Convert.ToInt32((string) Book.Element("ID").Value)))).Select(Book => new KeyValuePair<int,string>( Convert.ToInt32(Book.Element("ID").Value),(string)Book.Element("Name")));
```

How do i merge both with a single LINQ query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not save the result of the query and execute `Remove` on that variable?

```
var booksToRemove =
    xmlDoc.Descendants("Book")
          .Where(Book =>
              (Book.Element("ID") != null && 
              idsToRemove.Contains(Convert.ToInt32((string)Book.Element("ID").Value))))
          .ToArray();

booksToRemove.Remove();

var removedBooks = booksToRemove.Select(x => new
                                        {
                                            ID = (string)x.Element("ID"), 
                                            Name = (string)x.Element("Name")
                                        }).ToArray();
```

Comment: The removedBooks in this case will give me IEnumerable<XElements> which is bulk.I need only the key value pairs of ID and Name of the book.

Comment: Thanks. But booksToRemove.Remove(); should come at the end, otherwise removedBooks  will return null.

Comment: @Rockstart: Are you sure, have you tried it? I would find that rather strange. --- and indeed, it doesn't happen, I just tested it.

Comment: @Rockstart No it won't. The nodes will be detached from it's parent (the document) but will still exist.